# Searching for filenames containing ! (an exclamation mark ) on Windows

Tags: search, windows-7

On Windows 7, the following query used in folder search boxes fails to filter the files in a folder that have a "!" exclamation mark in them.

```
filename:!
```

Is there any way of doing this search please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your specific example `filename:"*!*"` seems to work in Win7 (Not sure about Vista)

[image: Win7 search]

I'd still recommend using 3rd-party tools like [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home), [BareGrep](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/) or [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) if you need to search for files with weird names or the content of files not indexed by Windows. (On Win9x/NT5 you can type <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> `*.dll` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `CreateThread` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you will find all DLLs on all local drives that contain the string "CreateThread", doing the same on NT6 is impossible AFAIK!)

Comment: That's all I need at the moment, so that's perfect, thank you!  Out of interest, how did you find that out?  I looked on the Advanced Query Syntax for ages, but couldn't find anything.  Such as: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx  and: http://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/

Comment: I remember bits and pieces of AQS but it was more of a guess than anything else (Which is why I said it seems to work) There should be more/other information about AQS on MSDN in the parts related to Windows Desktop Search for WinXP IIRC

Comment: Thank you. Been looking for this for months. In the meantime, I also switched to Agent Ransack because the inability to search for files with a ! was driving me nuts. Highly recommend it. The Win7 syntax is still awkward: you MUST specify "filename:" and the quotes and asterisks are more trouble than it's worth (considering this always used to work and is now a workaround for something "broken").

Comment: Be aware of escaping exclamation marks in Search Everything: http://superuser.com/questions/698125/search-everything-does-not-always-find-file-with-exclamation-marks